# Converting text to columns

Tags: python, parsing, text

I have a text file with weird formatting, as you can see header and columns do not contain a single column, but column may contains some spaces.

Example of raw file:

```
    Src IP addr  Port    Dest IP addr  Port       SSRC          Payload  Pkts         Lost   Max Delta(ms)  Max Jitter(ms) Mean Jitter(ms) Problems?
  1.2.3.4 17622  5.6.7.8 15932 0xEE531C47 ITU-T G.711 PCMU 60962     2 (0.0%)          106.78            8.55            0.34 X
```

What's the most efficient way to convert this text to an array:

```
['1.2.3.4','17622','5.6.7.8','15932','0xEE531C47','ITU-T G.711 PCMU','60962','2 (0.0%)','106.78','8.55','0.34','X']
```

- Columns 1-5 are 1 to 1.
- Column 6 may contain 3 tokens.
- Column 7 is 1 to 1
- Column 8 contains 2 tokens.
- Column 9-12 are 1 to 1.

Comment: your columns are space or tab separated?

Comment: What do you mean by "may contain 3 tokens"? How many words does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be more efficient than a regex solution, but regex could do better parsing.

```
line = '1.2.3.4 17622  5.6.7.8 15932 0xEE531C47 ITU-T G.711 PCMU 60962     2 (0.0%)          106.78            8.55            0.34 X'

parts = line.split()
# Make it readable
maxtokens = 15
numcols = 12
col6 = 5

# Get number of tokens for column 6
idx = col6 + len(parts) - maxtokens + 3

# Build the list
a = [p for p in parts[:col6]]           # Cols 1-5
a.append(' '.join(parts[col6:idx]))     # Col 6
a.extend(parts[idx:idx+1])              # Col 7
a.append(' '.join(parts[idx+1:idx+3]))  # Col 8
a.extend([p for p in parts[idx+3:]])    # Cols 9-12
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['1.2.3.4', '17622', '5.6.7.8', '15932', '0xEE531C47', 'ITU-T G.711 PCMU', '60962', '2 (0.0%)', '106.78', '8.55', '0.34', 'X']
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex is really fragile, but here goes:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "1.2.3.4 17622  5.6.7.8 15932 0xEE531C47 ITU-T G.711 PCMU 60962     2 (0.0%)          106.78            8.55            0.34 X"
>>> regex = re.compile(r'^([\d{1,3]\.[\d{1,3]\.[\d{1,3]\.[\d{1,3])\s+(\d+)\s+([\d{1,3]\.[\d{1,3]\.[\d{1,3]\.[\d{1,3])\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+\s+\(\d+\.\d+%\))\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\w+)$')
>>> matches = regex.match(line)
>>> list(matches.groups())
['1.2.3.4', '17622', '5.6.7.8', '15932', '0xEE531C47', 'ITU-T G.711 PCMU', '60962', '2 (0.0%)', '106.78', '8.55', '0.34', 'X']
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string and break that list into the way you want. There may be a regular expression solution, but this one is straightforward. Count the columns from 1 to 5, then based on the number of columns decide on 6th column, then work backwards for other columns.

```
>>> data = '  1.2.3.4 17622  5.6.7.8 15932 0xEE531C47 ITU-T G.711 PCMU 60962     2 (0.0%)          106.78            8.55            0.34 X'
>>> values = data.split()
>>> offset = len(values)-7
>>> values[:5] + [' '.join(values[5:offset])] + [values[-7]] + [values[-6] +' '+ values[-5]] + values[-4:]
['1.2.3.4', '17622', '5.6.7.8', '15932', '0xEE531C47', 'ITU-T G.711 PCMU', '60962', '2 (0.0%)', '106.78', '8.55', '0.34', 'X']
```